# Problems creating multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**What I want**

I want an Array looking like this:

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [paid] => 500
                [nname] => Lastname
                [vname] => Firstname
                [mail] => mail@mail.com
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [paid] => 200
                [nname] => Lastname2
                [vname] => Firstname2
                [mail] => mail2@mail.com
            )

    )
    [item2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [paid] => 100
                [nname] => Lastname3
                [vname] => Firstname3
                [mail] => mail3@mail.com
            )
)
```

It's an array where I have like multiple payments for one item. And I want to save all details from each payment as array into an array of the item.

**What I have**

```
$paidgift = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {              
                $nname = $row['nname'];
                $vname = $row['vname'];
                $paid = $row['paidprice'];
                $mail = $row['mail'];
                $gift = $row['title'];

                if (array_key_exists($gift, $paidgift)) {
                    //Item already exists in $paidgift
                    $paymentdetails = array('paid' => $paid,
                                            'nname' => $nname,
                                            'vname' => $vname,
                                            'mail' => $mail,    
                                            );
                    $paidgift[$gift][] = $paymentdetails;
                } else {
                    //Item doesn't exist in array $paidgift
                    $giftarray = array();
                    $paymentdetails = array('paid' => $paid,
                                            'nname' => $nname,
                                            'vname' => $vname,
                                            'mail' => $mail,    
                                            );

                    array_push($giftarray, $paymentdetails);
                    array_push($paidgift, $giftarray);
                }
}
```

**The result of my code**

Now I stuck with my code snippet. The problem is, that my code doesn't paste an existing items payment into the right array. This code section: `$paidgift[$gift][] = $paymentdetails;`

Instead it always creates a new item array and pushes the paymentdetails array into the newly created array.

Hope this is enough information to understand my problem. Please ask if something isn't clear.

Comment: `$paidgift[$gift][]` this isn't going to work. You need to specify a `key` or use `array_push()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check if the key exists it will be created if it doesn't in this case, see for example this code is perfectly fine

```
 $data = array();
 $data['test'][] = array("name","price","testing");
 $data['test'][] = array("other name","price","testing");

 var_dump($data);
```

There was no need to check if `$data['test']` exists.

So you don't need all of the code above this is simply enough

```
 $paidgift = array();

 while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // your data
    $data = array('paid' => $row['paidprice'],'nname' => $row['nname'],
                'vname' => $row['vname'], 'mail' => $row['mail']);
     // the gift
    $gift = $row['title'];
    // this is perfectly fine that's it
    $paidgift[$gift][] = $data;
 }
```

Comment: that's totally right! Thank you. you saved me some lines of code. It really works without testing if the item array already exists.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested)

If an array with key `$gift` (=title) exists it pushes the array with payment data into the array with that key.

If not it creates a new entry in `$paidgift` (an array) with `key` `$gift` for future storing.

```
$paidgift = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {              
                $gift = $row['title'];

                $paymentdetails = array('paid' => $row['paidprice'],
                                            'nname' => $row['nname'],
                                            'vname' => $row['vname'],
                                            'mail' => $row['mail']    
                                            );


                array_key_exists($gift, $paidgift) ? array_push($paidgift[$gift], $paymentdetails) : $paidgift[$gift] = array($paymentdetails);

}
```

Comment: I should notice that title isn't a really good key. If your title are unique than you can mark this comment as never written. Else you need to supply unique ids.